# Exiting CommandDialog by a user

Tags: node.js, botframework

I'm trying to find a way exiting a `CommandDialog` dialog by a user when using `back` or `cancel` or otherwise changes their mind.

```
var startCommands = new builder.CommandDialog();

bot.add('/', [
  function (session, results) {
    session.send('Hello %s', session.userData.name);

    // starting a dialog based on CommandDialog
    session.beginDialog('/begin');
  },
  function (session, results) {
   // This is where I want to be when dialog cancel of back is initiated by a user inside /begin
    session.send("you are back at the main dialog, start finshing process")
    session.beginDialog('/finish');
  }
]);

// defining a dialog for CommandDialog class
bot.add('/begin', startCommands)
bot.add('/finish', finishCommands)

startCommands.matches('yo', [
  function (session) {
    session.send('yo-yo');
  }
]);
startCommands.matches('tu', [
  function (session) {
    session.send('tu-tu');
  }
]);
startCommands.matches('.*', [
  function (session) {
    session.send('any-any');
    session.endDialog();
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

To exit a dialog, CommandDialog or otherwise, use a `triggerAction` on a dialog handler that calls `session.endConversation()`.

For example, here is an `exit` dialog which ends the conversation when the user sends the message `exit` or `quit`.

```
bot.dialog('exit', function (session) {
    session.endConversation('Goodbye!');
}).triggerAction({ matches: /(quit|exit)/i });
```